# Asking the dead to make dua for you : bidah or shirk?

Tags: shirk, bidah

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Someone I know does the following :

He hangs a picture of his dead parents in a photo frame on the wall, he touches the image of his parents and then asks the image of the parents in the photograph to make dua to Allah for him.

This person prays is a Muslim btw.

Is his action a serious bidah or shirk?

Comment: A dead person can't even make du'a for himself so it is pure ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

This link will answer your question in full detail https://archive.islamonline.net/?p=5419